# Show error and success messages in views total.js?

Tags: node.js, total.js

I want to send flash messages to views in `total.js` and i see an alternative approach with use of query string and check that flag for know what to show in view:

in controller:

```
this.redirect('/?success=1');
```

and in related view:

```
@{if query.success}
    //proper message
@{fi}
```

but i want to know is there any other approach available to show any status (error or success) messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases I use same approach but **I recommend** to do it on client-side via JavaScript if it's possible and my next recommendation is to send all forms via `AJAX`, always. Less code on server-side brings more benefits:

- less CPU and memory consuption on server-side
- output of view can be cached
- better performance
- smaller transmission data

---

Here is a **Flash module** with same functionality as in **Express.js**, but I don't recommend it: https://github.com/totaljs/modules/tree/master/Miscellaneous/flash

For rendering some flash messages you can use `controller.repository` object or `model` or you can create some View Engine Helper. There are many ways how to do it.

Comment: So I will do in client side. Thanks very much!